# Как отключить кнопку "Посмотреть организации в доме" и ссылку "Исправить неточность"?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-geocoding-api

При поиске по адресу, в баллуне появляются кнопка "Посмотреть организации в доме" и ссылка "Исправить неточность". Как их отключить?

Answer (score 1):

В балуне по умолчанию будет тот контент, который отдал Яндекс, убрать отдельно эти ссылки нельзя.

Вы можете собрать собственный [макет](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/layouts-docpage/?from=SO) для результата поиска и переопределить стандартный балун на него. Например, так:

```
   // Создаем экземпляр класса ymaps.control.SearchControl
   var mySearchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
            options: {
                noPlacemark: true
            }
        }),
   // Результаты поиска будем помещать в коллекцию.
        mySearchResults = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(null, {
   // Вот тут переопределяем балун
            balloonContentLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('$[properties.name]')
        });
    myMap.controls.add(mySearchControl);
    myMap.geoObjects.add(mySearchResults);

   // Выбранный результат помещаем в коллекцию.
    mySearchControl.events.add('resultselect', function (e) {
        var index = e.get('index');
        mySearchControl.getResult(index).then(function (res) {
           mySearchResults.add(res);
        });
    }).add('submit', function () {
            mySearchResults.removeAll();
        })
```

Интерактивный пример [есть в песочнице Яндекса](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_search_results?from=SO), правда там вместо балуна задаётся кастомный хинт.